# Armadillo subview issue

Tags: armadillo

The following fragment produces a compilation error:

```
arma::Mat<double> a(10,10,arma::fill::zeros);
arma::ucolvec w = whatever1;
whatever2 = a.rows(w).each_col() + another-col-vector;
```

The error is that arma::subview_elem2 has no member named each_col.

In a number of cases in Armadillo, the standard array functions are not always available on expressions or results of other function calls. Clearly the rows() function does not return a Mat object, but a subview_elem2 object, presumably for optimization. Another way to do this would be to declare all the array functions in interfaces/pure abstract classes that Mat and other internal classes, such as subviews, implement. It seems it should be possible to make all Armadillo array expressions interchangeable with array objects aside from write operations for expressions that only generate r-values.

So... I could wish for the following

a) An explanation of which methods are not available for which results.
b) Preferably, enabling all combinations of array methods that make sense.

Absent the above, how can accomplish the desired result, which is to evaluate the expression:

`a.rows(w).each_col()`

??

Answer (score 1):

## Some prior information about armadillo

The armadillo library uses templates heavily and most operations return [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates). Only when you assign the result to a variable the actual computation is performed. This is why you should not store the result of some computation with armadillo using `auto`.

For instance, given some matrices `A`, `B` and `C`, something like

```
auto D = A * B + C;
```

will not perform the computation and only the expression template is stored in `D`. On the other hand, using

```
arma::mat D = A * B + C;
```

will force the computation to happen and the result is stored in `D`.

## Solution to your problem

Particularly to your question, something like `a.rows(w)` returns an expression template of type `subview_elem2` (this file is defined in the source code `armadillo_bits/subview_elem2_bones.hpp`). This "temporary type" does not have a `.each_col` method, which results in the error you got. One way around is to store the result of `a.rows(w)` in a variable, but since you are not interested in the variable you can use the `.eval()` method. The `.eval()` method forces the expression template to perform the actual computation up to that point and thus the subsequent call to `.each_col` will work. That is, replace

```
a.rows(w).each_col() + another-col-vector;
```

with

```
a.rows(w).eval().each_col() + another-col-vector;
```

Comment: The [.eval()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eval_member) function works great in this context, though in general we should be careful where it's used. The documentation says: _"This function should be used sparingly and only in cases where it is absolutely necessary; indiscriminate use can degrade performance"_

Comment: Yes, I agree. Template expressions are used for a reason. They can optimize the operations when a value is actually needed (when you assign to a variable). When you use eval you are removing that possibility, but in this case it seems necessary. Armadillo is a very mature library and I would guess that the lack of an `each_col` method in `subview_elem2` is probably because that would either not be possible or it would be the same regarding efficiency as having an eval there.